# Components not appearing when nested in other components

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm am creating a music player app in React.js which consists of different tiles representing different genres of music. Here is the code in the main App.js file.

```
import React from "react";
import Genre from "./Genre.js";
import Row from "./Row.js";
//import genreData from "./genreData.js";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Row>
        <Genre name="Pop" bgColor="#d13636" />
        <Genre name="Rap" bgColor="#ef7421" />
        <Genre name="R&B" bgColor="#f7d021" />
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Genre name="Gospel" bgColor="a9d856" />
        <Genre name="Contemp. Christian" bgColor="#468f69" />
        <Genre name="Country" bgColor="#73ccdb" />
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Genre name="Kompa" bgColor="#2690cf" />
        <Genre name="EDM" bgColor="#908bb8" />
        <Genre name="Latin" bgColor="#9b60b6" />
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

For some reason the genre components aren't rendering inside the main row components nor is the background color appearing for each of the tiles.

Here is the code in from the Row.js and Genre.js files

```
import React from "react";

const Genre = props => {
  const bgColor = props.bgColor;
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: { bgColor } }} className="genre">
      <p>{props.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Genre;
```

```
import React from "react";

const Row = () => {
  return (
    <div className="row">
    </div>
  );
};

export default Row;
```

Here is also the main css file:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0%;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.genre {
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong and I even asked others before posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

There's to distinct issues here. First is the style.

In `Genre`, the value of a property in the [`style` object](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style) should be a string, so you'll want:

```
style={{ backgroundColor: bgColor }}
```

The second issue is in the `Row` component. The things you pass as a child to a component (like the `Genre` elements) are [passed via the `children` prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment), so you just need to pass that yourself:

```
const Row = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```